# How can I install the Clear-TcmPublicationTarget commandlet?

Tags: powershell, 2013

Apparently it is an out of the box Clear-TcmPublicationTarget cmdlet, but I never found it in my Tridion 2013 SP1 box.

Source: Ricks comment http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/decommission-a-publication-target

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only need to import the module and the cmdlet will be available:

```
Import-Module Tridion.ContentManager.Automation
Get-Command -Module Tridion.ContentManager.Automation
```

That will import the cmdlets and show you a list of them.

Comment: Brilliant! I could not find this in the manual.

Comment: It's here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-24D86D53-4122-41E8-A199-72E37D2873CB

Answer (score 5):

It works on my 2013 SP1 system.

First, I'd suggest using

```
get-module -listAvailable
```

to see if the module assembly is somewhere where your powershell can find it automatically. On my system,

gci env:PSModulePath

shows the Tridion bin directory as being on the module path, and the module is listed as available.

```
import-module Tridion.contentmanager.automation
```

should then succeed, after which typing

```
clear-t
```

followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion should find the Cmdlet for you.

If this fails, try using the overload of `ipmo` that accepts an assembly location as a parameter.