# How to decomission a publishing target with PowerShell?

Tags: core-service, 2013-sp1, powershell

I tried to decomission a publishing target with PowerShell and Peter's [Tridion Powershell Modules](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules).

Running this simple script did not work for me, I keep getting the error `Method invocation failed because [Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.SessionAwareCoreServiceClient] does not contain a method named 'DecomissionPublishingTarget'.`.

```
Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings -Version 2013-SP1
$client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
$client.DecomissionPublishingTarget("remove-me-tcm:0-1-65537")
```

Update: removed the ConnectionType setging from the script above, that has nothing to do with it, the DecomissionPublishingTarget should be available on sessionless clients as well. Added -Version setting cause this is for SDl Tridion 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me. It must be because it's not using the 2013 SP1 version of the client. Probably due to this known issue: [First run connects to 2011 endpoint](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules/issues/8).

Try to persist your 2013 settings (add -persist to Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings) and try in a new PowerShell session. That should do the trick.

Comment: Confirmed, the trick is to set the config with -Persist and then open a new PowerShell prompt. https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/401622b56f8ae427c5bc

Answer (score 3):

A helpful workaround is given by [Peter earlier](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/5023/88). You can use the built in PowerShell module.

```
Import-Module Tridion.ContentManager.Automation
Clear-TcmPublicationTarget "remove-me-tcm:0-1-65537" -Verbose
```

That works beautifully, but more of a workaround, no answer to the question.